# Include this file in project

Tags: objective-c, ios

Trying to debug a UILabel and am trying to follow the instructions on this page:

http://ramin.firoozye.com/2008/12/11/easy-uiview-debugging-on-the-iphone/

which mentions:

> Include this file in our iPhone XCode project and build it for
>   debugging.

Does that mean simply import it into a .m file like this?

```
#import UIViewExtras
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just need to drag the file 'UIViewExtras.m' into your Xcode project, so that it lies alongside the rest of your source code files. Nothing else, no #imports.